# SAP CDS Odata URL in ADF

Tags: azure-data-factory

I am new to azure data factory (ADF) and trying to create a dataset from an Odata source. The only problem here is that the Odata URL was developed in SAP CDS and so has custom query options as shown below:

"http://XXXXXXX/ZC_XXX_TU_SR_ACTIVITY_CDS/ZC_XXX_TU_SR_Activity(p_warehouse='E065',p_from=datetimeoffset'2021-06-01T00:01:01',p_to=datetimeoffset'2021-08-11T23:01:01')/Set"

1. When choosing the path I expect only one path in the options but I get 2 - ZC_XXX_TU_SR_Activity and ZC_XXX_TU_SR_ActivitySet so I am unsure of which one to use even though I have tried both
2. When writing the query, I have tried:

?(p_warehouse='E065',p_from=datetimeoffset'2021-06-01T00:01:01',p_to=datetimeoffset'2021-08-11T23:01:01')/Set

?(p_warehouse='E065'&p_from=datetimeoffset'2021-06-01T00:01:01'&p_to=datetimeoffset'2021-08-11T23:01:01')/Set

?(p_warehouse=%27E065%27&p_from=datetimeoffset%272021-06-01T00:01:01%27&p_to=datetimeoffset%272021-08-11T23:01:01%27)/Set

I have also tried to use all 3 options without the '?', "()" and the '/Set' but I am still getting errors.

I get this error:

"*query (p_warehouse='E065',p_from=datetimeoffset'2021-06-01T00:01:01',p_to=datetimeoffset'2021-08-11T23:01:01')/Set failed with status code InternalServerError and message `SY/530`An exception was raised.*"

I have run out of ideas now and don't know what else to do. Please help. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

**Note:** The OData connector copies data from the combined URL: [URL specified in linked service]/[path specified in dataset]?[query specified in copy activity source].

Here, I could see that you have the root path as `http://XXXXXXX/ZC_XXX_TU_SR_ACTIVITY_CDS` and the resource path as `ZC_XXX_TU_SR_Activity` or `ZC_XXX_TU_SR_ActivitySet`.

So, there is an issue passing the query in :

**System Query Option :**

> System Query Options are query string options that a client may use to
> alter the amount and order of data returned by an OData service for
> the URL-identified resource. All System Query Options have a “$”
> character before their names.

**Custom Query Option:**

> Because the character "$" is reserved for system query options, custom
> query options MUST NOT begin with it. A custom query option can start
> with the “@” character, however this can cause custom query options to
> clash with function parameter values supplied via Parameter Aliases.
>
> This URL addresses, for example, give a ‘secURLtytoken' through a
> custom query option.

This is for more information: [URL Conventions (OData Version 3.0)](https://www.odata.org/documentation/odata-version-3-0/url-conventions/)